# How to customize a part of the directive template?

Tags: angularjs

Assuming I have a simple directive:

```
<div id="testdirective">
   <span>Test Directive</span>
- Custom HTML Here -
</div>
```

How can I make the directive such that when a user clicks on a button in index.html, it would call on a method in the Controller that would show the directive, but would change only:

> - Custom HTML Here -

based on the button clicked?

index.html

```
Assume the following is part of a Controller

<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
```

Behavior is , when clicking on "button1" the content for button "1" would be loaded, if click on button "2", specific html for "2" would be loaded.

I would like to keep that "check if button 1 is clicked logic" to be within the directive itself and not the controller if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having actual text that gets replaced, you can bind to a variable on your scope. This variable is your model. e.g.

```
<div id="testDirective">
    <span>Test Directive</span>
    {{myText}}
</div>
```

This will bind the text in that section of the DOM with the `myText` scope attribute. Your controller would be able to set the initial value (or more likely your link function if you are writing a directive).

```
$scope.myText = '- Custom HTML Here -'; // Some initial text
```

You buttons can use [`ng-click`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) to implement the change in the model as so

```
<button ng-click="myText='button 1 content'">1</button>
<button ng-click="myText='button 2 content'">2</button>
```

I won't write a full directive for you here, but you can use the examples [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to see how you would do this. If you need to show this directive only when a button is clicked you can take a look at [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) too.

Comment: This does not work, I want to use custom HTML. Not just text. If used <b>My Text</b> it would not show a bold version of it and would output the text... tags and all. I want it to be "compiled", but im not sure how to best do it. The HTML is complex, and may be very different depending on what case it is (1 or 2). It is pretty specific to the directive, so I am not sure I would want to clutter the primary Controller that captures the button "onclick" event with all this custom directive HTML.

Comment: For this case maybe an `ng-switch` is better then? You can keep the HTML in your partial and switch on your model instead.

Comment: The issue with ng-switch is all the html is "hard coded". I might just want 'one case" to be loaded depending on button pressed with $http. (Unless there is some trick to use ng-switch with the $http so that its only "compiling" relevant HTML as necessary?)  If each case (i.e. 1 or 2) was a form, each with the same "submit" button to different URLs, is this still one directive or multiple directives?